# Desktop User Control vs Web User Control

Tags: c#, user-controls, webusercontrol

I have made a user control that works fine with desktop applications but now I want to use that with Web Applications too. I have used C# as programming language. Can anybody suggest me how to do that? Any kind of help is highly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

please see below link, it shows how to add windows form control in aspx page.
http://weblogs.asp.net/spano/archive/2007/09/19/hosting-a-windows-form-control-in-a-web-page.aspx

you can also see : http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Place-Windows-Control-To-Web-Form.aspx